# BigQuery + Firebase Campaigns google/cpc

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

Faced problem with BigQuery + Firebase:

In Firebase UI (Analytics - Conversions - 'ecommerce_purchase') I see purchases and google / cpc campaigns attributed to them.

For example, in Firebase UI I see google / cpc campaign '.Search_Category_Gucci_All_undefined' with purchases and revenue (value), but if i do request in BQ, I see other google / cpc campaigns, for example '!Smart_Shopping_Campaign' which is also exists, but see no '.Search_Category_Gucci_All_undefined', no reveue(value) data or number of purchases,

Example of my request :

```
SELECT 

traffic_source.source AS Source,
traffic_source.medium AS Medium,
traffic_source.name,

event_param1.value.string_value AS transaction_id, 
event_param2.value.int_value AS Revenue,
event_date AS Date,



FROM `name_of_my_project.analytics_172959255.events_202012*`,
UNNEST(event_params) event,
UNNEST(event_params) as event_param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as event_param2
WHERE event_name = "ecommerce_purchase"
AND event_param1.key = 'transaction_id'
AND event_param2.key = 'value'
AND event_date BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231'
AND traffic_source.source = 'google'



ORDER BY event_param2.value.int_value desc
```

So if someone knows how to fix it, help please

Thanks

Comment: GBQ is not a commonly used acronym for BigQuery, so I recommend spelling it out in full.

Comment: Maybe try and expand beyond only the ecommerce_purchase event. Sometimes some of the more unique campaign types like Smart Shopping end up under a different event.

So I'd start by finding all those events connected with Search_Category_Gucci_All_undefined and then filtering it down.